# POST request blocked in react axios due to CORS error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, cors

I am trying to send a POST request to an API with multipart data.

I test the API in postman and everything works fine in Postman. But when I call the API in react, it gives me CORS error.

I cross-checked the URL, Header, and Data, all seems OK for me. I go through multiple Stack Overflow question on the same topic and found that I need to pass allow-cross-origin along with the header. I added that in my header but didn't able to solve my problem.

The error which I got in the console is:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

**API Calling Code**

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const header = {
    "userid":localStorage.getItem("userid"),
    "token":localStorage.getItem("token"),
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }

const URL="https://api.hello.com/dashboard/venue_updated";

export function updateVenue(data,name,venue_type,email, phone_no,callback, errorcallback){
    console.log(header);
    axios.post(URL,data,{
        params:{
            name,
            venue_type,
            email,
             phone_no,
        },
        headers:header
    })
    .then(res => {
      if(callback != null){
         callback(res);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if(errorcallback != null){
         errorcallback(err);
      }
    })
}
```

I used to import this in my component and call it on the form-submit method.

Comment: which backend technology u r using ?

Comment: You add the headers on the backend api side, as answered below. Implementation may be different depending upon what backend framework you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

axios call with that header in React doesn't solve CORS.
Server's response must have `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"`

check network tabs and see server's response.

Answer (score 4):

you have to add in your backend like this . (This example for nodejs)

```
app.use(cors(), function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
```

for Enable All CORS Requests

```
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Is it work for all domains if I put '*' in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' field.

Comment: yes it 'll work for all domain .

Comment: I updated the header, however, the problem didn't solve.

Comment: share what you have done in your que . make sure you r changing in backend .

Comment: https://prnt.sc/swzd4z

Comment: i have edited my ans please check once .

Answer (score -2):

Go this URL code and Enable CORS settings if you have access to it.
https://api.hello.com/dashboard/venue_updated