# Axios Post request in React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, axios

I am new to react native and trying to post a request to an api, but I am having different results and I am not able to understand why this is happening what I am missing.

Below is the code and after that a short description is given about the code.

```
import { Button, TextInput } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";
const SignUp = (props: any) => {
const { navigation } = props;
const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    checkName: false,
});

const handleNameChange = (val: any) => {
    if (val.length !== 0) {
        setData({
            name: val,
            checkName: true,
        });
    } else {
        setData({
            name: val,
            checkName: false,
        });
    }
};
const toSend = {
    name: data.name,
};
async function handleSubmit() {
    console.log("Component Did Mount");
    let axiosConfig = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
    };

    axios
        .post(
            "https://cloud-api.herokuapp.com/api/users/signup",
            toSend,
            axiosConfig
        )
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
<TextInput
    placeholder="Name"
    onChange={(val: any) => handleNameChange(val)}
/>;
return <Button title="signUp" onPress={handleSubmit}></Button>;
};

export default SignUp;
```

I am not able to demystify this error:

If I a add concrete value to the name state like this { name: "Carla" } and do not enter any value in the text field on front end and press the button, then my request is successfully posted without warning [1] and error[2].

But when I try to use front end to enter value in text box and then sent it on a button click then this warning [1] prompts on browser console and after some time the server respond back with [2].

[1]

> index.js:1 Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance
>   reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the method
>   `isDefaultPrevented` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is
>   a no-op function. If you must keep the original synthetic event
>   around, use event.persist(). See react-event-pooling for
>   more information.

[2]

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://cloud-api.herokuapp.com/api/users/signup' from origin
>   'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. SignUp.tsx:121 Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83) xhr.js:178 POST https://cloud-api.herokuapp.com/api/users/signup net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: The error is because of the cors in the backed server.
Add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"  in the backend api response header.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62296248/12318562. May this help you.

Comment: To the commenters [The security model for XMLHttpRequest is different than on web as there is no concept of CORS in native apps.](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network)

Comment: `prompts on browser console` Is it a web app or a native app? In your example code you don't do anything with a passed event (onChange or onSubmit) so that warning is not from code you posted in your question.

Comment: @HMR this is a native app, I am only debugging my app on browser.